# How to prevent ps from truncating the process name

Tags: ps

Following command outputs only first 25 characters of the process name (cmd) on the screen. How do I get it to display the full process name?

```
 ps -eo pid,cmd,etime
```

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/567648/ps-comm-format-always-cuts-the-process-name

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is swap the order of outputs: if `cmd` is last, it will be extended to the full width of the terminal:

```
ps -eo pid,etime,cmd
```

If that's still not sufficient, you can add a `-w` (wide) output modifier

```
ps -ewo pid,etime,cmd
```

An additional `w` gives even wider output

```
ps -ewwo pid,etime,cmd
```

(In both of these cases, the output may be wrapped by the terminal.) If you really must have the original field order, then you can specify an explicit width for the cmd field using the syntax `field:width` e.g.

```
ps -eo pid,cmd:80,etime
```

This can be combined with the `-w` flag(s) if necessary e.g.

```
ps -ewo pid,cmd:160,etime
```

The width of a particular output column can also be forced wider by using a longer header string e.g.

```
ps -eo pid,cmd=my_very_very_very_long_command_that_I_want_to_see_more_of,etime
```

Comment: It depends on `ps` implementation. E.g., the BusyBox `ps` does not implement `-w`, and, AFAICT, always truncates. (And in that case, it seems like one must either parse `/proc` themselves, or find a better `ps`.)

Answer (score 8):

Pipe the output to `cat`.

```
ps -eo pid,cmd,etime | cat
```

Comment: of course this is the answer

Comment: This definitely *isn't* the answer. 'cmd' is still truncated.

Answer (score 2):

```
ps -A  -o pid,user:20,%cpu,%mem,comm,args
```

Comment: Can you add some comments to your proposed solution, please?

Comment: `ps -A  -o ppid,pid,user,%cpu,%mem,args` works on MacOSX — user:20 is an error and comm,args is redundant.  It seems essential for args to be last.